# grails does not write to log file

Tags: grails, logging

I have the following in my grails config log4j section:

```
appenders {
  file name: "usageAppender", file: "${logDirectory}/onetract3.log"
}

root { error 'stdout', 'usageAppender' }

info usageAppender: "grails.app.services.com.onetract.onetract.UserService"
```

The file "onetract3.log" is successfully created, however nothing is written to this file.

I can see in the console that the info is handled correctly.

```
2014-03-09 20:09:06,912 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] INFO  onetract.UserService  - New candidateRelations for: com.onetract.onetract.Person : 18
```

Grails version is 2.3.5

Any ideas on why this isn't getting written to the log file?

Edit: 10.03.1014, set additivity to false.

```
info additivity: false 
    usageAppender: "grails.app.services.com.onetract.onetract.UserService"
```

Comment: All appenders inherit from root by default. In this case, usageAppender will only log errors in the file. In order to log that particular info level log for the service class, you would have to specify the log level as `info additivity: false usageAppender: "grails.app.services.com.onetract.onetract.UserService"` so that it won't inherit from the root anymore.

Comment: Hi @dmahapatro, thanks for the response, I tried that as you suggested however I still do not see it in the logs. In addition now I no longer see the log entry in the console. Interestingly, if I change the root from "error" to "info" I get two KB of logs written to onetract3.log, however only up until the point where the application is running, then the logging stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the following entry:

```
file: "${logDirectory}/onetract3.log"
```

Before the application is running, this works, afterwards not.

The workaround is to explicitly tell the appender where the file is, i.e.

```
file: "logs/onetract/onetract3.log"
```

This then works.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
// Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
//
//appenders {
//    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
//}

    appenders {
        rollingFile  name:'myLogFile', 
        file:'log/myLogFile.log', 
        threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.ALL, 
        maxFileSize:10485760
    }
    root {
        error 'myLogFile'
        additivity = true
    }

   info "grails.app","com.test"
   warn "grails.app","com.test"
   debug "grails.app","com.test"
   error "grails.app","com.test"
   fatal "grails.app","com.test"
   trace "grails.app","com.test"

   error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
          'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
          'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
          'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
          'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
          'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
          'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
          'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
          'org.springframework',
          'org.hibernate',
          'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
```